# Attempting to code a command that runs out of .emacs

Tags: emacs

I'm attempting to set up a command that automatically reloads my .emacs file bound to a control key.
I have used ielm mode and the defun portion evaluates fine, but the keyboard macro is where it's failing

**Defun starts here**

```
(defun reinit () 
    "reloads .emacs file "
  (load "/home/phoenix/.emacs"))
```

**keyboard shortcut starts here**

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c r") 'reinit)
```

in ielm both evalute as reinit, however, if I attempt to reload and run I get **wrong type argument: commandp, reinit**

Any ideas on how to get this working?  I'm using Emacs 26.3.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the assistance @steve-vinoski.
I went back and read it again, and I was able to figure it out.
In case anyone else has this issue with 26.3 or 27.1, don't write a separate defun then call it later - it won't work.

On **one line only** do the enter this  ("C-c r"  maps to Control-C then r, change that to what ever you want!)

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c r") (lambda () (interactive) (load "/your/home/directory/.emacs")))
```

It works like a champ!  Thanks again!

(change the your/home/directory/.emacs to whatever you call your init file and point it to wherever it lives in your directory.